# .htaccess url rewrite for blog posts

Tags: .htaccess

I'm building a site from scratch and having trouble understanding url rewriting. My blog posts are found at `example.co.uk/blog/blog_post.php?post-slug=example-post-title` and I'm trying to get them to display at `example.co.uk/blog/example-post-title`.

Can someone advise exactly what my htaccess file should look like to achieve this? I've searched for answers but can't find anything that explains it to a complete novice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^blog/blog_post.php?post-slug=(.*)$ /blog/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```